# Finding a subspace using combination formula

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is a question from my textbook
[image]

The answer I have is something like this: 
let $X_1$ and $X_2$ $\in K$,and a,b $\in R$, because $T(aX_1+bX_2)=aT(X_1)+bT(X_2)=0+0=0$, so K is a subspace of $R^{10}$

I can understand it, but, well, I think the definition of subspace is $H$ is a subspace of $V$,  $u$, $v$ $\in H$
if we can prove that

1. $u+v$ $\in H$
2. $cu$$\in H$

that's the definition in every textbook, we can't we have a simplier definition such as $H$ is a subspace of $V$ as long as $au+bv\in H$, where a and are scalars, wouldn't it be much more simplier?

Comment: Both are equivalent. A subspace is defined as a non-empty subset of a vector space that is closed under summation and scalar multiplication. That is equivalent to saying it is a non-empty subset closed under linear combinations.